# Basic arithmetic within a function not working

Tags: php, integer, division, integer-division

I have a PHP function I'm using to count files within a directory.

```
function getFileCount($path) {
$size = 0;
$ignore = array('.','..','cgi-bin','.DS_Store');
$files = scandir($path);
foreach($files as $t) {
    if(in_array($t, $ignore)) continue;
    if (is_dir(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t)) {
        $size += getFileCount(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t);
    } else {
        $size++;
    }   
}
return $size;
}
```

That works correctly, but I need to divide $size by 2 before returning.

If I do 'return $size / 2;' then 60 becomes 22.5. 72 becomes 19.125. It doesn't make sense to me. I've also tried intdiv(), tried multiplying by 0.5, etc., and I've gotten varying results but none of them correct.

I know this is probably something extremely basic.

If I do the division outside of the function it works correctly, but I want to handle that before returning an integer.

Comment: count the array and subtract the static. I guess, it will save the extra work of loop

Comment: As far as I can tell I need it to be recursive in order to files within subdirectories can also be counted. Is there any way to just apply the division to the final, returned value of $size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create a wrapper function?

```
function getFileCountDivided($path) {
    return getFileCount($path) / 2;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it's also returning the same incorrect values (60/2 = 22.5, etc.)

Comment: what do you get if you do $x = getFileCount($path); var_dump($x); I get int 60, and it divides fine for me

Comment: That does work, but then int() is also printed out. Is there a way to escape that?

Comment: I only suggested that for debugging purposes. I think the division is working but something is going wrong where you echo the output, can you show some more of the calling code

Comment: I'm calling it within a WordPress query loop. I've tried a handful of variations here as well, but the most relevant bit is: $path = getcwd() . '/wp-content/uploads/screenshots/' . $class . '/'; echo getFileCountDivided($path);

Comment: try replace your echo with something like this, that will force the formatting of the floating point number, printf("%5.2f", getFileCountDivided($path));

Comment: That does work, although the numbers appear with decimals as well. Oddly enough though, after reverting it everything is displaying correctly. I'm not quite sure why or what changed since I've been experimenting and rapidly uploading new versions of the file. It seems to work correctly now but I'm sort of worried that if I sneeze it's going to go back to how it was.

Comment: It is possible that wp is doing caching, if you don't want decimals, then use intval(getFileCountDivided($path)) instead

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I'm going to accept your answer even though we did most of the work in comments.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of the recursion, subdirectory count divided by 2 is going to be divided again as part of the upper directory count.
You can wrap this function in another one which is going to divide the final count once and return. Keeping track of the directory depth seems like too much of an overhead to me in this case, although that's an option as well.